# Why is tkinter Text not adding color?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to add a background, foreground color to a word in the Text widget , it inserts the text but without the color.

Why is that happening?

Here is the part of code I am using:

```
for line in decoded.splitlines() :
   if name in line :
       conversation.tag_add(line, "1.0", "1.4" )
       conversation.tag_config(line, background="yellow", foreground="blue")
conversation.yview(END)
```

"decoded" is a string, and name is the word. I'm looking for in the string which I defined in the beginning of script.

I want it to color the line if the variable name is in it but I cant seem to do that.

Comment: @Rinzler , down voting because the question had some grammar or punctuation missing is not an excuse , this should be based on the question context, and if you down voted for that but could not answer it yourself then you should not have either.

Comment: I did **not** downvoted dude. I was just suggesting.

Comment: In that case i am sorry then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index you give to `tag_add` is an absolute index. Even though you are looping over all the lines, you're only ever adding highlighting to the first four characters of the text widget over and over and over.

The other problem is that you're giving a very unusual tag name. You're using a tag named after the contents of the entire line (ie: if the line of text is "hello, world", you're creating a tag named "hello, world"). It actually is probably safe, but it's highly unusual.  Tag names normally are simple strings like "bold" or "highlight" or something like that. If you're truly wanting a unique tag for every line, I recommend a simple incrementing name/number like "tag-1", "tag-2", etc.

Comment: Why am i not seeing anything highlighted then ? this is the first time i use tag_add and i am not really familliar with how it works, if you can give a code exemple it would be nice.thank you

Comment: I want it to color the line only if there is the variable name in it

Comment: I finally managed to get it , i was misunderstanding the use of the tag_add() , i used a modified version of the Text widget that tags the specified word or line  without having to precise the length , this is where I was having trouble but tganks for clarifying that